# have a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception try to send gcm message ??

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm getting a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException exception when attempting to send a message to the GCM server from my app server. Registration was successful on the client side.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

class Notify {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            Sender sender = new Sender(
                    "AIzaSyCd9HdSlq51nLzoqxMaFLsxWaoxxIz6-bU");

            ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            devicesList.add("APA91bFzbdNTf5CVsnSpkPJxMTCUCnjruluaerQcONQq9f20aaHw1CMNcVFgBsnLd6gUQT5TxrV2WY5WBw9U9u4Paj3dAXgRbaATc9a2Gp0voF3h5elX3Be0r3xw3Kun2HZT1m3D8L6IwCkXtTiILIfVasiKd2uN3w");
            devicesList.add("APA91bFzbdNTf5CVsnSpkPJxMTCUCnjruluaerQcONQq9f20aaHw1CMNcVFgBsnLd6gUQT5TxrV2WY5WBw9U9u4Paj3dAXgRbaATc9a2Gp0voF3h5elX3Be0r3xw3Kun2HZT1m3D8L6IwCkXtTiILIfVasiKd2uN3w");

            // use this line to send message with payload data
            Message message = new Message.Builder()
                    .collapseKey("1")
                    .timeToLive(3)
                    .delayWhileIdle(true)
                    .addData("message",
                            "this text will be seen in notification bar!!")
                    .build();

            // Use this for multicast messages
            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
            sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);

            System.out.println(result.toString());
            if (result.getResults() != null) {
                int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
                if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                }
            } else {
                int error = result.getFailure();
                System.out.println(error);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

that's the code

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument cannot be null
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.nonNull(Sender.java:553)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.getString(Sender.java:534)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:365)
    at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:261)
    at com.example.server.Notify.main(Notify.java:34)
```

and thats my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of your AIzaSyCd9HdSlq51nLzoqxMaFLsxWaoxxIz6-bU - use another one.

Comment: it's not solved my problem. ı try another apikey but nothing change still same error .

Comment: I put my api key to your code - and its works.Try another one(refresh few times).You turn on Google Cloud Messaging for Android in services?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the reading response part. It should be like :

```
MulticastResult multiResult = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
List<Result> results = multiResult.getResults();

for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
    Result result = results.get(i);

    if (result.getMessageId() != null) {
        // Success
        String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
        if (canonicalRegId != null) { 
            // same device has more than one registration id.Update it
        }
    } else {
        // Error occurred
        String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it seems that there is a problem with the apiKey or device ids. Where did you get those device ids? Those should be generated in the client side. And also why did you add the same device id twice?

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer above was selected, I believe this is the cause.

https://code.google.com/p/gcm/issues/detail?id=7

The issue is fixed in master, but the jar in the SDK is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

The GCM server is returning an error like "401 Unauthorized", but there is a bug in the GCM code where it throws this `IllegalArgumentException` instead of the intended `InvalidRequestException`. You need to attach source and then set a breakpoint at at this code in `com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender` to see what the actual HTTP error is.

```
int status = conn.getResponseCode();
String responseBody;
if (status != 200) {
  responseBody = getString(conn.getErrorStream());
  logger.finest("JSON error response: " + responseBody);
  throw new InvalidRequestException(status, responseBody);
}
```

Basically `conn.getErrorStream()` is returning `null` here so you never see the `InvalidRequestException`.

The code above is from the latest 1.0.2 release. There is a related fix in the latest GCM GIT repository, https://code.google.com/p/gcm/issues/detail?id=7, but looking at changes they made to [Sender](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.java) it still seems like it's going to be an issue.